# Pull data from JSON string

Tags: c#, json

I'm attempting to extract data from a JSON string in C#, so far I have been recommended to use JavaScriptSerializer. I'm not having much luck however as when using int.Parse I'm getting less than minimal results.

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            string json = wc.DownloadString("www.redacated.com/" + args[0]);
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            dynamic result = serializer.DeserializeObject(json);
            var url = int.Parse(result["file_url"]);
            Console.WriteLine("URL: {0}", url);
        }
```

The linked url returns this:

```
{
    "file_size": 6606723,
    "file_url": "redacted",
    "preview_url": "redacted",
    "title": "redacted"
}
```

This is causing the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at Workshopdownloader.Workshopdownloader.Main(String[] args) in c:\users\*\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication7\ConsoleApplication7\Program.cs:line 29
```

Comment: `int.Parse(result["file_url"]);` <-- did you mean `"file_size"` ?

Comment: If you're sure it's always a number, maybe call `.Trim()` on the value?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest Json.NET - Newtonsoft. It's a breeze to use

Comment: I'm needing to extract file_url out of the JSON response.

Comment: @user1372896 - If you're trying to extract the URL (which will most likely be a string), why are you trying to parse it to an `int`?  Just due `var url = result["file_url"];`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a POCO class to represent your object:

```
public YOUR_POCO
{
    public int file_size {get; set;}
    public string file_url {get; set;}
    public string preview_url {get; set;}
    public string title {get; set;}
}
```

then all you need is to use JSON .Net to deserialize it into it:

```
YOUR_POCO poco = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YOUR_POCO>(output);
```

Access it as you would any other object

```
// use the file size
var file_size = poco.file_size;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code is cool, just change your conversion.

You are initially trying to convert a string to become and integer of which cannot happen in any case whatsoever, so the compiler throws a FormatException when it gets there

```
var url = int.Parse(result["file_url"]);
```

Change to

```
var url = result["file_url"];
```

Comment: "rying to convert a string to become and integer of which cannot happen" - Not true, you can convert a string to an integer, as long as the string being converted is capable of being an integer.  I.e., "123" can be converted, "ABC" cannot.